# callback function is inside another function in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using one function which contains some data processing concept.that means processing the "OData" (accessing remote data from URL -service).

```
bindTo: function () {

        if(!sf.util.isNullOrUndefined(this.model.Series))
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.model.Series.length; i++) {
             if (sf.util.isNullOrUndefined(this.model.Series[i].Visibility))
                    this.model.Series[i].Visibility = 'visible';
            var series = this.model.Series[i];
            if (sf.util.isNullOrUndefined(series.Points))
                series.Points = [];
             if (series.dataSource) {
                 if (series.dataSource.data instanceof sf.DataManagar) {
                     this._processOData(series);
                 } else if (series.dataSource.data != null && series.dataSource.data.length > 0) {

                     this._processJsonData(series.dataSource.data, series);
                     this.Draw();

                 }
             } 

            }
        }
    },
```

Please refer below processoData function

```
_processOData: function(series) {
    var chart = this;
            var queryPromise = series.dataSource.data.executeQuery(series.dataSource.query);
            queryPromise.done(function (e) {
                chart._processJsonData(e.result,series);  

                **chart.Draw();**
            });
    },
```

we have to wait for some time to fetch data from URL so I used callback function here "done" function and then only I called draw function for chart.  but in other cases there is no need for accessing remote data that means I need to call the draw function directly. if it is a remote data processing I need to wait until I get data and then only am going to draw the chart but in other cases I don't need this condition.

so bindTo function which calls "Draw" function for chart. I need to some jquery function which waits/executes until call back completed like this below jQuery function.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

i tried like below code.

```
$.when(this.bindTo()).then(function(e) {
            chart.Draw();
        });
```

but it didn't wait until callback function in bindTo to complete. its called draw function directly before processing **"odata"**

so **bindto** function is need to wait until the callback function which is inside the bind to function to complete and then only I need to call draw function.

Comment: if you want to use a function with `when` it has to return a `promise` http://api.jquery.com/promise/  https://tutsplus.com/lesson/deferreds/

Comment: please provide any example how to use promise in "when"

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/

Comment: basically you create a JQuery.Deferred object and return its .promise(). inside the function you resolve or reject the promise depending on outcomes

Comment: i cant get idea how can i use this here. how to change $.when  using "promise" here

Comment: well I can't tell much cause I don't understand the logic flow and I don't know the library you are using

Comment: just i need bindto function need to wait until it contains all callback competed and then only i need to call "Draw" function